# Conditional processing in Maven projects

Tags: maven, build, conditional-statements

I have some configuration settings that are in the Maven project that I'd like to keep there for building into a newly set up system but not touched if the configuration setting already exists. One of the problems I had is that when I deleted the setting from the build, it also deleted the setting from the target server when I did a build.

What would good alternatives be?

Comment: Can you show a kind of example what you are talking about in particular...

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to move the particular set-up for the new systems in a [Maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and activate the profile only based on either an environment variable or the existence/non-existence of a file.

For instance, from official documentation, you can activate the profile if a certain environment variable exists, not exists or exists with a certain value.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>environment</name>
        <value>test</value>
      </property>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Please also note that, as from official documentation:

> Note: Environment variables like FOO are available as properties of the form env.FOO. Further note that environment variable names are normalized to all upper-case on Windows.

Alternatively, the profile can be activated on a certain file (existing or missing), as following:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <missing>path/to/missing/file</missing>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

If your set-up cannot be applied to any of these two cases, you could (as an example) anyway adapt it to create an harmless file which would then deny any further set-up.

- harmless file missing > profile activated > set-up performed
- harmless file existing > profile not activated